# How do I set default settings for project view? (for all projects)

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Whenever I import a project, these settings are set to some default values and I need to change them again if I want them different. How do I set them once and for all?

[image: screenshot]

I'm using Android Studio 1.2 right now. The answer for IntelliJ Idea (if it's different) is interesting, too.